# Dispatching pattern without a known type

Tags: python, dispatcher

I'm trying to create a function dispatching in Python to have different "overloads" for types I don't necessarily have access to in the current library.

What I know about these types are their attributes, e.g. through `hasattr`.

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def fun(value):
    # do something with value

@fun.register(MyType)
def _(value):
    # do something specific for MyType with value
```

Again `MyType` isn't something defined anywhere, but any type that verifies having certain attributes.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) with `runtime_checkable` decorator?

Comment: @SUTerliakov, didn't know about Protocol, thx. I tried but could not get it to work. I would have expected it to. I don't quite understand the docs on method resolution order so do not have an explanation as to why it does not.

Answer (score 0):

The [Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) class enables an interesting approach. (thx @SUTerliakov).

```py
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable

# Define protocols which identify objects having specific attributes.
# We need to test for instances at runtime.

@runtime_checkable
class FooProtocol(Protocol):
    foo: str

@runtime_checkable
class BarProtocol(Protocol):
    bar: str
```

Define a function which 'dispatches` according to supported protocol

```py
def explicit_dispatch(thing):
    if isinstance(thing, FooProtocol):
        print('implements FooProtocol')
    elif isinstance(thing, BarProtocol):
        print('implements BarProtocol')
    else:
        print('neither FooProtocol nor BarProtocol')
```

Create objects of 'unknown' type.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
# dataclass enforces the setting of attributes

@dataclass
class FooObject:
    foo: str

@dataclass
class BarObject:
    bar: str

isFooObject = FooObject('foo')
isBarObject = BarObject('bar')
isObject    = object()
```

Confirm function identifies instances of unknown classes.

```py
explicit_dispatch(isFooObject)
explicit_dispatch(isBarObject)
explicit_dispatch(isObject)
```

prints out...

```
implements FooProtocol
implements BarProtocol
neither FooProtocol nor BarProtocol
```

`Protocols` don't work with `singledispatch`. You'll have to decide for yourself whether or not this is compatible with your coding style.

Comment: Although Protocols look to be useful towards your goal, this does beg the question of whether there is a good rationale for why the library you are using does not provided access to the classes in the first place.